# How to update values inside a promise

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

In my todo app, I am trying to use cloud function to update some values when a new task is added.

```
exports.updateAttributes = functions.database
  .ref('/companies/{coid}/tasks/{fid}')
  .onCreate(event => {

      const task = event.data.val()
      const root = event.data.ref.root

      const coid = event.params.coid
      const cid = task.clientId
      const sid = task.senderId
      const tid = task.technicianId

      // [1] I can not set these variables are still pending so I send then to a Promise
      const company = root.child(`/companies/${coid}`).once('value')
      const sender = root.child(`/users/${sid}`).once('value')
      const technician = root.child(`/users/${tid}`).once('value')

      task.status = "pending"
      task.createdAt = `${(new Date())}`
      task.pin = Math.round(Number(Math.random() * (9000 - 1000) + 1000))
      task.senderAndStatus = `${sid}|pending`
      task.technicianAndStatus = `${tid}|pending`

      return Promise.all([company, sender, technician]).then(result => {
          const c = result[0].val()
          const s = result[1].val()
          const t = result[2].val()

          // [2] Here I have access to the variables, but unable to save 

          // [3] using variable from a Promise
          //t.sender = s
          // [4] accessing task directly
          task.company = c

          // console.log("SENDER", s); // returns sender name
          console.log("COMPANY", task.company); // returns company name, assigned to a task
      })
  })
```

In comment **[1]**, I am unable to save the value from company, sender or technician because they are still pending, so I send them to a promise.

Inside a promise **[2]**, I have access to the value, can assign the value to task **[3]** and **[4]** and access them through a task.

How do I save the task after I assign these values?

Comment: "[2] Here I have access to the variables, but unable to save". Why can't you save? You'll need to use firebase-admin to write to the database, by the way.

Comment: What do you mean by "save the task"?

Comment: Also, I'll point out that `task` is not a promise, but you're passing it to `Promise.all()`, which doesn't make sense.  You can access `task` just fine from inside your `then()` callback.  Also, you're defining a `const t` twice in your callback.  That should fail - you can't define a const twice.

Comment: I don't know why, i'ts what i am trying to figure out. By "Save the task" meaning, updating the task with values from company, sender and technician.

Comment: What's keeping you from saving the task?

Comment: I user `admin.database().ref()` as @Sidney suggested and it worked.